# React Native | Why is my function running immediately, rather than just onPress?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-props

I am just starting to grasp props in react native so I am hoping that this is a simple solution.

I want the state of the form to update to bring the user to the next page in the form and I want the state of the response to update as well - both when the user presses the button component (onPress).

However, what I'm seeing when I console.log is that the update state function is running immediately, rather than when the button is pressed - so it is going directly to the second "page" of the form.

### Form Component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { View, Text} from 'react-native';
import Happiness from './Happiness';

const StarterForm = () => {
    const [formStage, setFormStage] = useState(1)
    const [happinessLevel, setHappinessLevel] = useState('')

  console.log(formStage)
  console.log(happinessLevel)

  const increaseTheStage = (happiness) => {
      setHappinessLevel(happiness)
      setFormStage(formStage +1)
  }

  switch (formStage) {
    case 1:
      return (
        <Happiness 
        passHappiness={increaseTheStage}
        />
      )
    case 2: 
        return (
          <Text>This is the case of two</Text>
        )
  }
}

export default StarterForm;
```

### Happiness component

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Happiness = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
            <Text>Which of the following best classifies your happiness?</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.passHappiness('Excellent')}>
              <Text>Excellent</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
  )
}


export default Happiness;
```

### Expected Results

I expect the following when the first screen opens:

```
console.log(formStage) = "1" 
console.log(happinessLevel) = ""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using anonymous functions

You are calling the function right away, switch it to this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.passHappiness('Excellent')}>
```

Now you have created an anonymous function which calls `passHappiness` with the parameter 'Excellent' illustrated below:

```
() => props.passHappiness('Excellent')
```

### Using bind

You can also use the bind method to "bind" the parameter "excellent" to the function

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={props.passHappiness.bind(this,'Excellent')}>
```

More on the bind method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).